# Detecting enter key in java

Tags: java

I have tried to get user input with scanner and if user press enter then proceed to next input statement. but it print all at once.

```
public class MainRDS 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String path;
        String name;
        String ext;
        String date;

        System.out.println("Directory search by path, name, extension, content and date.");
        System.out.print("\nEnter Starting directory for the search (link c:"+"\\"+"temp) : ");
        path = in.next();

        System.out.print("\nEnter the file name (like myFile or enter for all) : ");

        if((name = in.nextLine()).length() > 0)
        System.out.print("\nEnter the file extenstion (like txt or enter for all) : ");

        if((ext = in.nextLine()).length() > 0)
        System.out.print("\nEnter last modified date (like 11/21/2012 or enter for any) : ");

        date = in.nextLine();
    }
}
```

output :

```
Directory search by path, name, extension, content and date.

Enter Starting directory for the search (link c:\temp) : c:

Enter the file name (like myFile or enter for all) : myfile

Enter last modified date (like 11/21/2012 or enter for any) :
```

required output:

```
Directory search by path, name, extension, content and date.  
Enter starting directory for the search (like c:\temp): c:\temp 
Enter the file name (like myFile or enter for all):  
Enter the file extension (like txt or enter for all): txt 
Enter content to search for (like comp121 or enter for any):  
Enter last modified date (like 11/21/2013 or enter for any): 11/1/2011
```

Comment: I've just tested it and it does wait for user "enter" key. (Only added "new" before Scanner(System.in)). Do you want to print the user input?

Comment: Can you share sample input and corresponding output that you get from above code ? Also expected output/behavior ?

Comment: have you posted a running code? what is this `Scanner in = Scanner(System.in);` where is `new` keyword or there is something new you using in Java17? by the way I am still on java7 thats why asking.

Comment: I add new but it only get file anme and then print all.

Comment: please share the complete class if your class conatins only this code?

Comment: No. Every in.nextLine waits for the user input. What do you see? what do you expect?

Comment: exactly. as @baraky said it always wait for user input on in.nextLine either it is in any `if` statement or anywhere (without if)

Comment: i update the code and post sample output and required output

Comment: @Ahmar - please delete your question as opposed to editing out its contents.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is perfectly fine.You just need to replace your first line

```
Scanner in = Scanner(System.in);
```

with

```
Scanner in =new Scanner(System.in);
```

I am unable to understand that how you tested this code, because this is not a running code due to `Scanner in = Scanner(System.in);` this line

Answer (score 1):

Got It!

you need to use:

```
path = in.nextLine();
```

Otherwise, `name = in.nextLine()` catches the path's "enter" key and doesn't get any value.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your code and it does make the user press the "enter" key.. can you explain what you are looking for more specifically? As others have stated just change your Scanner:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
path = in.next();
```

To

```
path = in.nextLine();
```

Tested it, all is printed out and worked fine!

Comment: it is working .Have you tested that `if((name = in.nextLine()).length() > 0)` is working or not?

Comment: wait a minute, something still wrong... i'll check it and update my answer later